# mysql search and compare between 3 tables

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables in a mysql database

---

table1(invoice_items)

invoice_id  model_no

---

table2(invoices)

invoice_id  customer_no

---

table3(customer_details)

customer_no  email_address

---

i want to search the fields in model_no within table1 for all the invoices with same model_no

but the real data i want is the email addresses of the customers who bought said models but i have to go through 3 tables to get it

is there a search query that will output searching/comparing across 3 tables ?

sorry hopefully i have given enough information for my answer
i am using mysql query browser

thank you all in advance
regards
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This *simple* solution joins the tables together using `INNER JOIN`.

The `INNER JOIN` keyword selects all rows from both tables as long as there is a match between the columns. E.g. If there are rows in the "invoice" table that do not have matches in "invoice_item", these invoices will NOT be listed.

[image]

[Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

```
Select cus.emailaddress, inv1.invoice_id, cus.customer_no
From invoice_item inv1
Inner Join invoices inv2 using (invoice_id)
Inner Join customer_detail cus using (customer_no)
And inv1.model_no =xxxx;
```

Answer (score 0):

Unable to test this currently, but the basic idea is to first query all `customer_no` that have bought models using a `JOIN` between tables `invoice_items` and `invoices`, like so:

`SELECT b.customer_no FROM invoice_items a, invoices b 
WHERE b.invoice_id = a.invoice_id`

Secondly, use the MySQL `IN` keyword to join `customer_details` table with this result set, selecting `email_address` if the `customer_no` is present. This would result in query such as, or similar to, this:

`SELECT c.email_address 
FROM customer_details c
WHERE c.customer_no 
IN
(
   SELECT b.customer_no FROM invoice_items a, invoices b
   WHERE b.invoice_id = a.invoice_id
)`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all very much for your ideas.... I managed to work through it

Please see below for my working solution

```
SELECT a.invoice_id, a.model_no, c.email_address

FROM invoice_items a, invoices b, customer_details c

WHERE a.invoice_id = b.invoice_id AND b.customer_no = c.customer_no
AND a.model_no = "xxxxxxxx";
```

Comment: Congrats on figuring out the solution.  See this article to see the difference between using the where statement and inner join.  https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins